# How to take picture with openCV in android?

Tags: android, opencv, camera

While searching on the internet, I found that proper way of doing this is using `takePicture` method of `CameraBridgeViewBase` . But that doesn't work, because `CameraBridgeViewBase` doesn't have `takePicture` method. So, what should I do?

P.S. This question has been asked before about 6 years ago ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187378/android-opencv-camerabridgeviewbase-take-picture)). But there are problems in code and I don't feel like it is the correct way of doing this

Comment: I must say that with the latest (v.4.5.0) version the [approach of extending](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26223614/192373) `org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView` is still valid.

Comment: @AlexCohn, if that is the one and only approach, then I have to that way. Write something as answer, if there will not be any suitable answer I will accept that.

Comment: I believe that this can simply be marked as duplicate. But let us wait a bit, maybe somebody else has a better answer for you.

Comment: The truth is, OpenCV is not built to take pictures, this whole process is a workaround. It does not take a picture *with* OpenCV, it takes a picture without breaking OpenCV. There has been some discussion about switching from the old deprecated **Camera** API to the new **camera2** API, but this seems to be irrelevant now. Soon, a new easier **CameraX** API will become production grade, and hopefully OpenCV will switch to this new API. Then, we will need a new way to take pictures without breaking OpenCV.

Comment: @AlexCohn, thank you for your answer, I missed that point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the latest (v.4.5.0) version the [approach of extending](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26223614/192373) `org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView` is still valid.

***OpenCV*** is not built to take pictures, this whole process is a workaround. It does not take a picture with ***OpenCV***, it takes a picture side by side with ***OpenCV***, without breaking it. There has been some discussion about switching from the old deprecated **Camera** API to the new **camera2** API, but this seems to be irrelevant now: soon, a new, easier **CameraX** API will become production grade, and, hopefully, ***OpenCV*** will switch to this new API. Then, we will need a new way to take pictures without breaking ***OpenCV***.

Comment: To add on to this - now that CameraX releases and common patterns have been established, it is probably best to utilize the CameraX Analyzer class which is designed to efficiently handle image processing (this basically means abandoning the JavaCameraView pattern). Within your Analyzer you can use the OpenCV utilities like `Imgproc` just like before to detect contours etc. on the imageProxy after converting it to the OpenCV `Mat` format. This also means you can use OpenCV with Jetpack Compose, which has been working great with CameraX for over a year now.